# Typing @ symbol in front of parameter names in comments

Tags: support

How does someone go about writing a SQL Server parameter name into a comment?  I tried to ask if an author got his parameters out of order in a comment, but I was rejected because it said "Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified".

Comment: This problem probably occurs across all the SE sites.  It might be more appropriate to raise it on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Seems quite localised to database stuff. PITA. Typical code monkeys annoying the DB types... :-)

Comment: I $%&^ing HATE that "only one additional @ user can be notified" message. I don't care, just post the damn thing and don't notify anyone. I'm sure this has been raised on meta SO, right?

Comment: I would suggest using the backtick character like so `@param1` `@param2` `@param3`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
I would suggest using the backtick character like so `@param1` `@param2` `@param3`
```

provides this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t56c.png]